# Cannot run Firebase code in Swift unittests

Tags: swift, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set up some unittesting for my Firebase database. But when I try to run Firebase code in my unittest function, it will not run. I do something like this:

```
func test() {
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.ref.child("test").setvalue(["test": "test"])
    print("done")
}
```

So that code should set a value of "test" in my database, print "done" to the console, and return success for the test. It does the latter two, but does not access my database in any way. I run the same code from anywhere in my app and it works just fine.

I tried in `super.setup()` running `FirebaseApp.configure()` to check if I am connected to the app, but when I run this command I get:

```
caught "com.firebase.core", "Default app has already been configured"
```

Which makes me think that Firebase is properly set up. But I still cannot access. How do you access your Firebase app from swift unittesting?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that the call to `setValue()` is asynchronous. So by the time you `print("done")` that value has not actually been written to the database yet. Not sure if that's the cause, but it's suspicious about the way you've written the code. To know for sure when the write is done, add a completion listener to the `setValue` call.

Comment: That is true that `setValue()` is asyncronous, but regardless it should still set a value in the database even after the `test()` is complete. 

I also tried using expectations using this [link](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/unit-testing-asynchronous-swift-code) with no luck. 

Doing something like `sleep(5)` after the Firebase call had no effect either.

I am pretty sure it is an issue with connecting to Firebase from the unittest function